# HttpWebRequest upload large data stream to Gitlab API file

Tags: c#, .net, gitlab-api

I need to upload (post) or append (put) a large data stream to a new or existing Gitlab file ('out_file'), but I get the error as shown.

[gitlab api](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/repository_files.html#create-new-file-in-repository) says that content tag is mandatory in URL, but this is size limited.

The contents data stream must be from any file type (image, doc, pdf, txt, etc) and be larger than 1 MB. The URL is valid and 'contents' is already a
base64 string.

I have seen many examples online but I cannot seem to get these to work for me. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

N.B. Exception handling omitted from below code for brevity.

```
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System;
using System.Text;
...

public static void Upload(String id, String out_file, String contents)
{
    String blank = ""; // to satisfy gitlab api content arg.
    String url = "https://gitlab.xxx/api/v4/projects/"+id+"/repository/files/" 
+ out_file +"?ref=master&branch=master&commit_message=test&encoding=base64" 
+ "&content="+ blank;

    ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
    request.Method = "POST"; // or PUT
    request.Headers.Add("PRIVATE-TOKEN", token);
    request.Headers.Add("Transfer-Encoding", "chunked");
    request.KeepAlive = true;
    request.Proxy = null;
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

    byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(contents.Trim());
    request.ContentLength = buffer.Length;
    request.GetRequestStream().Write(buffer,0,buffer.Length);
    request.GetRequestStream().Close();

    // ERRORING HERE
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse(); 
    String output = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
    Console.WriteLine(output);
    response.Close();
}
...
Unhandled exception. System.Net.WebException: An error occurred while sending the request.
---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request.
---> System.IO.IOException: The response ended prematurely.
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.FillAsync(Boolean async)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.ReadNextResponseHeaderLineAsync(Boolean async, Boolean foldedHeadersAllowed)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpMessageHandlerStage.Send(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.SocketsHttpHandler.Send(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.Send(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpMessageInvoker.Send(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, Boolean async, Boolean emitTelemetryStartStop, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.Send(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.SendRequest(Boolean async)
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
```

Comment: Do you have a response code returned from the server, with maybe an error description?

Comment: No, just the exception.